# Rule with empty recipe and empty prequisite and pattern rule

Tags: makefile

This is a snippet of the make file:

```
main.o :

%.o: main.c  strlen.h main.h common.h 
@echo $^
```

My question is that since main.o has an empty prerequisite and recipe then why the pattern rule is listing the dependency for main.o? As output shows like :

```
main.o : main.c strlen.h main.h common.h
```

Please explain any body help is appreciated!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rule without a recipe simply adds any provided prerequisites to the given target.  In other words, there can be only one rule with a recipe for a given target, but there can be as many rules without recipes for the same target as you like.

This:

```
foo.o: foo.h
foo.o: bar.h
foo.o:
foo.o: biz.h
foo.o: foo.c
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

is identical, from the point of view of make, to this:

```
foo.o: foo.c foo.h bar.h biz.h
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Sir!!!!!!!!!!!!! the empty rule can be after the last recipe also because we have to add many dependency after the first make generated. So basically what  I am asking is can we put an other rule like foo.o : main.h after last line(foo.o : foo.c  $(CC) -c -o $@ $<).

Comment: They can come in any order, as long as only one of them has a recipe.